# XMLDocument Load(XmlReader) vs Load(Stream)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

I am using XMLDocument Load function with input arguments as stream xml data. I see a violation for doing that [CA3075](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca3075). For string data, it is suggested to create XmlReader object and pass it to XMLDocument Load function with XMLResolver value set to null in arguments.

```
    System.IO.StringReader sreader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sreader, new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = null });
    doc.Load(reader);
```

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca3075#solution-3

I wanted to understand what difference does it make of using XMLReader vs stream as arguments?

Comment: Stream will read everything.  XmlReader will look for errors in data and report.  You can use XmlReader.Create(sreader);

Comment: Using XmlReader can stop error from occurring.  Normal xml is well formed meaning the there is one root tag.  Often you get xml the has multiple tags at root. So  using following works :             XmlReaderSettings setting = new XmlReaderSettings();
            setting.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create("input", setting);

Comment: @jdweng what impact would `XmlResolver=null` create? Also i wanted to Load stream data not string. And also does XMLReader reveal information while throwing exception
?
Can i use the below mentioned snippet for stream data?
  
```var streamdata = # Streamed xml data
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(streamdata, new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = null });
doc.Load(reader); ```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlresolver?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0  the resolver is checking both syntax of xml and connection.